# Why is Nano refusing to use syntax colouration?

Tags: colors, alpine-linux, nano, syntax-highlighting

I am running Alpine Linux 3.18. I have installed `nano 7.2` and `nano-syntax 7.2`, and my `$TERM` is set to "xterm-256color", but I'm not getting any syntax colours in Nano.

The file is a Ruby ".rb" file, and I even tried adding `--syntax=ruby` to the command. No dice.

I get colours for exactly the same Ruby file in Debian.

What should I do?